# Unable to convert ipython notebooks to pdf

Tags: fonts, errors

I am unable to convert the ipynb notebooks to pdf.
I have installed texlive-latex-base package, also i do have pandoc installed. I can convert the notebooks to markdown and html but not pdf. 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that font ecrm1095 is missing. It belongs to the EC fonts. They are available in package `texlive-fonts-recommended`. In addition, `cm-super` should be installed to get Type1 versions of the EC fonts.